# sharepoint Designer workflow 2013 - set Item level permissions for multiple users from the single person and group fied

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, item-level-permissions

I am cerating a SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013.

Trigger action - When item is created.

On creation of an item I am setting unique permissions based on two person and group field from an item. **(i.e. Owner and Additional Creator)**

**Owner --> allow multiple selection is - false**

**Additional Creator --> allow multiple selection is - true**

I am using rest end point`/addroleassignment` to set unique permissions. It works perfectly for **Owner** field as there is alway single person for this field.

However **Additional Creator** field contains multiple users. I am not sure how to grant permissions to multiple users from single field through sharepoint designer.

Or how can I can iterate through all the users from **Additional Creator** field ans use `/addroleassignment` end point ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To loop all users from multiple people column, you can refer to:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8a890b5-f5fb-447f-b96f-9f3abdb7e178/forum-faq-sharepoint-2013-extracting-values-from-a-multivalue-enabled-lookup-column-and-merge?forum=sharepointgeneral

It works for multi-value enabled lookup column, you can refer to the same way for the multiple people column.